# Random page rendering error: A stray renderRoot() invocation is causing bubbling of attached assets to break

Tags: 8, theming

I have a D8 site that's in development and I am getting this error thrown at random on pages which most of the time render quite happily. There doesn't seem to be any real pattern in it.

I can see that it looks like it's designed to prevent the renderer creating an infinite loop (the code is on line 133 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php), but it isn't really clear what's actually causing it. The log error is pretty useless really.

Anyone seen this and found out the cause? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is caused by [Renderer::renderRoot()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3ArenderRoot/8.4.x) in a wrong place, see the docs:

> Renders final HTML given a structured array tree.
>
> Calls ::render() in such a way that placeholders are replaced.
>
> Should therefore only be used in occasions where the final rendering
>   is happening, just before sending a Response:
>
> - system internals that are responsible for rendering the final HTML
> - render arrays for non-HTML responses, such as feeds
>
> (Cannot be executed within another render context.)

Look for `renderRoot()` in custom code. Check if you need to render at all (most times you need not) and don't render too early, only in theming when there is a render context collecting the bubbled up metadata. Then replace it with [Renderer::render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3Arender/8.4.x).

The random behavior is probably because of caching.

Comment: Thanks for this, yes there was a renderRoot in some custom code, seems to have sorted it :-)