# How can I display the block title when rendering a block using Twig Tweak?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

Block title when using twig-tweak plugin, not showing. I created a block-type view. And using the module's [cheat sheets](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet), I called:

```
{{ drupal_view('views_name', 'block_1') }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to manually type it on your twig, as per https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak/issues/2738781

If you don't want to type it on twig, a work around would be to add a "Text area" to your view's Header and use replacement patterns, `<div class="view-title">[view:title]</div>`.

---

Alternatively, you could ditch Twig Tweak and do it yourself by creating a variable:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables) { 
    // replace HOOK with the template file you're trying to add it to. Ex: node, page, block etc..
    $view  = views_embed_view('view_name', 'block_1');
    $variables["my_view"] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($view);
}
```

Then in the template file you just do `{{ my_view }}`

Comment: In theming use render(), not renderRoot(), when you really need to render yourself. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251924/random-page-rendering-error-a-stray-renderroot-invocation-is-causing-bubbling